# Can't find replacement for switch

Tags: switches, components

I am trying to repair a nespresso machine(not a job, just for fun) and the PCB had the following switch:

[image]

I tried to google it as *"switch"*, *"switch 4 pin"*, *"1552"*, but nothing returned a switch similar to it, not even a datasheet. am I searching it the wrong way?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like a solenoid to turn the switch off electrically.

Comment: Looks like a custom part. What’s wrong with it? What measurements can you make?

Comment: you don't google `switch` ..... google the manufacturer of the machine and the words "parts catalog"

Comment: Sorry for the delay, that's a Double Pole Single Throw switch, the coil is used by the circuit to turn it off. At the top part of it, you can see that it has some sort of a leaver similar to light switches we use in homes that allows you to turn it on manually.

Comment: In practical terms this is an **off topic part sourcing question**.  The device you picture could as readily be considered a relay (with manual override?) as a manual switch (with coil override) but the heavy spade lugs make it appear to be used for substantial power (such as the heating element).  In theory, if you understood _exactly_ how it was used (eg, could derive the engineering requirement specifications) you might find something else, in practice you probably need the original part...

Comment: There's also no evidence presented so far that it's actually this item which is bad, and not something like the circuit which drives it or which it powers.  Check the thermal fuses, etc...